# Jasmine spies function call

Tags: javascript, jasmine

There is the following code:

```
  $scope.clickByPoint = function(marker, eventName, point) {
    var geocoder, location;
    $scope.options.info.point = point;
    $scope.options.info.show = true;
    $scope.searched = false;
    $scope.address = "";
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    location = {
      lat: parseFloat(point.latitude),
      lng: parseFloat(point.longitude)
    };
    geocoder.geocode({ location: location }, function(results, status) {
      $scope.searched = true;
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        $scope.address = results[0].formatted_address;
      }
      return $scope.$digest();
    });
  };
```

Please, tell me, how I can 'spy' calling to 'geocoder.geocode' and execute fake code instead of it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. I understand your idea, but your code doesn't work. Can you check it and edit?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new in Jasmine

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to make call a mock of the geocode function, just to check if your controller function is treating it right, is that it?

You should use Jasmine Spy's "call and return value", this lets you make a call to a function in your test and hardcode the result you want this function to return. Example:

```
describe("A spy, when configured to fake a return value", function() {
  var foo, bar, fetchedBar;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      setBar: function(value) {
        bar = value;
      },
      getBar: function() {
        return bar;
      }
    };

    spyOn(foo, "getBar").and.returnValue(745);

    foo.setBar(123);
    fetchedBar = foo.getBar();
  });

  it("tracks that the spy was called", function() {
    expect(foo.getBar).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("when called returns the requested value", function() {
      expect(fetchedBar).toEqual(745);
  });
});
```

You can check the jasmine docs to further info here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_and.returnValue